# Are questions having to do with popular media off topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that some SEs have [popular-*] tags and some don't. Why is there that inconsistency? Does Stack Overflow discourage people from asking questions about popular media?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a `popular-x` tag?

Comment: @RobertHarvey `popular-math` on the math SE is defined as "any mathematics in popular-media", physics has a `popular-science`, english has `pop-culture`

Comment: Everybody has science, math and English courses in high school.  Everybody has a popular opinion on the subjects.   Programming, well, not exactly.  Fairly sure that Stallman never got laid for what he did.

Comment: @HansPassant off-topic, Stallman's problem with getting laid was probably less the programming but more the eating the sores off his feet.

Comment: @HansPassant but I think that, at least in dealing with popular culture, we all know that programming is fairly prevalent. It seems that it comes up often enough to merit it's own tag, like if someone had a question about the Unix system used in Jurassic Park.

Answer (score 5):

Don't be misled by the presence or absence of a tag on a site. Stack Overflow has a [windows-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-7) tag, which is appropriately used for some programming questions (*"Foo() used to work on Vista, but fails on Win7, why oh why?"*). It doesn't open the door to questions about the use of Windows 7 in general. [Some tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info) make appropriate use clear; some, like windows-7, don't.

In short: if a question abides by Stack Overflow's [rules for topicality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you're good. If it makes reference to, say, a popular show on HBO, well, you'll probably get more views and votes for that. Still need to be answerable, practical, and programming-related.

I enjoyed reading the question you posted earlier today on Stack Overflow, on the meaning of "fleventy-five". You or others deleted it, but it's still up on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835198/what-is-fleventy-five). You put a lot of effort into finding meaning, but I think the death knell for it on SO was that it was obviously, IMO, a throwaway joke, a made-up word, and because of that lacked the "answerable" and "practical" aspects.

Comment: That is actually what this post is about :P I didn't realize that it was a throwaway joke, and thought it was some sort of system that I was previously unaware of haha. People mentioned that it should be closed since it has nothing to do with programming, but the hexadecimal system really has more to do with programming than math or engineering, although it has it's roots and uses in engineering.

Comment: @JFA: well, if you're using hex math in a programming context, you should be good. And if it's interesting and answerable, you should be good (not sure [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808646/why-is-the-first-four-bytes-of-java-class-file-format-is-cafebabe) would stick around if it were asked today, but it was popular four years ago). In the end, you're not plugging a question into the Stack Overflow compiler - humans review content, and if you have a really interesting questions, well, rules get broken. Not often, but sometimes, and it's usually worth it.

Comment: Canonical example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/23897

Comment: I was interested in learning notation for something I was previously unaware, so it was a serious programming question.